# R regex - replacing nth match

Tags: regex, r

Suppose you want to replace the second string match with the second element in the vector replacement. For instance:

```
x <- "CBCADEFGHI"
pattern <- "(A|D|C)"
replacement <- c("X","Y","Z")
```

How would you go about replacing only the second pattern match, which is "C" because its the second pattern that is discovered, with the corresponding replacement vector element "Z"?

Desired Output:

```
"CBZADEFGHI"
```

Comment: I don't know how come you choose the corresponding replacement vector element?

Comment: Why was `"A"` not replaced with `"X"`, but `"C"` _was_ replaced with `"Z"` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Since C is the third letter in `pattern` and Z is the third element in `replacement` I wanted to replace C with Z

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  It's the 2nd match that is replaced by corresponding elements in replacement

Comment: @akrun This is clear...thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully I understand this correctly.  Here's my idea.

```
## find the position of the second match
g <- gregexpr(pattern, x)[[1]][2]
## get the individual letter elements out of 'pattern'
s <- scan(text = gsub("[()]", "", pattern), sep = "|", what = "")
## replace the position 'g' in 'x' with the matched element in 'replacement'
substr(x, g, g) <- replacement[match(substr(x, g, g), s)]
## resulting in
x
# [1] "CBZADEFGHI"
```